# In Javascript, how do I generate a random element out of a list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

Suppose I have a list of strings. How do I generate a random one?

Comment: If you need to get random strings in a non-duplicative manner (not specified above), consider using a "shuffle" such as a Fisher-Yates. (After the shuffle you can just 'shift' off the front of the Array.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting random value from an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-random-value-from-an-array)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You mean, get a random array member?

```
var strings = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * strings.length);

var randomString = strings[randomIndex];
```

[See it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/5T4kL/).

If you mean a random string, it is a little different.

```
var randomStrLength = 16,
    pool = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789',
    randomStr = '';


for (var i = 0; i < randomStrLength; i++) {
     var randomChar = pool.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * pool.length));
     randomStr += randomChar;   
}
```

[See it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eBabD/).

Of course, you can skip the `pool` variable and do `String.fromCharCode()` with a random number between 97 (`'a'.charCodeAt(0)`) and 122 (`'z'.charCodeAt(0)`) for lowercase letters, etc. But depending on the range you want (lowercase and uppercase, plus special characters), using a pool is less complex.

Comment: Wouldn't using Math.ceil() there cause one never to select the first element (0)?

Comment: @Andrew Barber: Not never, but extremely seldom. You would get a distribution over four indexes, where the first occurs only when the random number is exactly zero.

Comment: @Guffa: extremely seldom -- you mean on an average 20% of the time ?

Comment: @Andrew Barber I changed that a while back when I realised my mistake :)

Comment: @Mahesh Velaga: No, something closer to 0.00000000000001% of the time.

Comment: @Guffa: Its a little tricky I think, what happens when the array size is low ? lets say 5 and what if the random number generated is less than 0.2 (which will be on an average 20% of the time)?

Comment: @Mahesh Velaga: The index will only be 0 for the random number 0.0, but for any value 0.0 < n <= 0.2, the index will be 1. For example `Math.ceil(0.0000000001*5) = 1`.

Comment: @Guffa: Sorry, my bad .. I started off with taking ceil in my mind and in between I switched to floor, thanks for patiently answering my non-sense questions :)

Answer (score 8):

Alex and Mahesh are right on, just wanted to demonstrate how I might implement their solutions if I felt like living dangerously.  Which I do.

```
Array.prototype.chooseRandom = function() {
  return this[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length)];
};
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
a.chooseRandom(); // => 2
a.chooseRandom(); // => 1
a.chooseRandom(); // => 5
```

Comment: Reputation be damned, I love changing the prototype!

Comment: Wait, can you guarantee that sample output? :P

Answer (score 2):

```
var randomString = myStrings[Math.floor(Math.random() * myStrings.length)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var rand = 0; 
var newPic = []; 
var pic = [1,2,3] //length = 18 for ( var i=0; i<18; i++ ){ 
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*19); 
    newPic.push(pic[rand-1].slice()); 
} alert(newPic);
```