# Getting a random value from a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, random

Consider:

```
var myArray = ['January', 'February', 'March'];
```

How can I select a random value from this array using JavaScript?

Answer (score 2300, accepted):

It's a simple one-liner:

```
const randomElement = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
```

For example:

```js
const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];

const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * months.length);
console.log(random, months[random]);
```

Comment: @SapphireSun this is correct. Note the `Math.floor(Math.random(...))` call, which rounds down.

Comment: Ahh, I've learned something new. I was discussing the case where it equals EXACTLY 1, but apparently (according to W3Schools) Math.random is between 0 inclusive and 1 exclusive. My bad.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I recall `var rand = myArray[Math.random() * myArray.length>>0]` being slightly faster

Comment: I prefer this variant: `var rand = myArray[Math.random() * myArray.length | 0]`

Comment: Be aware that this function returns `undefined` as soon as you pass an empty array. It might be helpful to throw an exception in that case.

Answer (score 134):

If you've already got [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) or [lodash](https://lodash.com) included in your project you can use [`_.sample`](http://underscorejs.org/#sample).

```
// will return one item randomly from the array
_.sample(['January', 'February', 'March']);
```

If you need to get more than one item randomly, you can pass that as a second argument in underscore:

```
// will return two items randomly from the array using underscore
_.sample(['January', 'February', 'March'], 2);
```

or use the [`_.sampleSize`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#sampleSize) method in lodash:

```
// will return two items randomly from the array using lodash
_.sampleSize(['January', 'February', 'March'], 2);
```

Comment: When using typescript: Be aware that the return type would be "string | undefined" instead of "string" given a string array.

Answer (score 62):

You may consider defining a function on the Array prototype, in order to create a method `[].sample()` which returns a random element.

First, to define the prototype function, place this snippet in your code:

```
Array.prototype.sample = function(){
  return this[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.length)];
}
```

Later, to sample a random element from the array, just call `.sample()`:

```
[1,2,3,4].sample() //=> a random element
```

<sub>I'm releasing these code snippets into the public domain, under the terms of the [CC0 1.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/).</sub>

Comment: And this does what?

Comment: @KenSharp it allows you to call `.sample()` on any array to get a random item

Comment: Extending native object types should be avoided. I have deleted my answer, seeing it was upvoted a lot, but promoting bad practice. For more discussion on this issue see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice and https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-extend-native

Comment: @MarkusAmaltheaMagnuson That's a good point. However, defining custom methods on prototypes isn't necessarily an issue, especially if done so sparingly and outside of library code. The prototype provides an alternative solution that is quite pretty (in my subjective opinion) and exposes sometimes-overlooked but interesting parts of the language, at least when used sparingly. For nearly all application code, this won't cause issues, so it comes down to a matter of taste.

Comment: See my own answer on extending the instance instead of the prototype.

Answer (score 51):

`~~` is much faster than `Math.Floor()`, so when it comes to performance optimization while producing output using UI elements, `~~` wins the game. [MORE INFO](https://coderwall.com/p/9b6ksa/is-faster-than-math-floor)

```
var rand = myArray[~~(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
```

But if you know that the array is going to have millions of elements then you might want to reconsider between Bitwise Operator and `Math.Floor()`, as bitwise operators behave weirdly with large numbers. See below example explained with the output.

```
var number = Math.floor(14444323231.2); // => 14444323231
var number = 14444323231.2 | 0; // => 1559421343
```

Comment: Link is dead, however interesting post and I shall be using this more than `Math.floor` now :)

Comment: using "bitwise not" operator, while faster, is not that readable, so you have to choose what is more important to you

Comment: double tilda - interesting... I learned something new.

Comment: For those who want to understand what it means, `~` is a bitwise `not`, which reverses the `1`s and `0`s in a binary number. As with all bitwise operators, it first converts the number into a 32 bit integer, which all you really want. Using `~~` restores the original as a 32-bit integer.

Comment: As for `Math.floor()`, All functions have an overhead which includes storing and restoring the original state. Generally, optimising compilers will look for opportunities to copy the code in place to avoid that overhead, but, with a dynamic language such as JavaScript, it’s harder to predict.

Answer (score 43):

The shortest version:

```js
var myArray = ['January', 'February', 'March']; 
var rand = myArray[(Math.random() * myArray.length) | 0]
console.log(rand)
```

Comment: What does `| 0` do?

Comment: It will turn Float to Int, same as Math.floor.

Comment: @KenSharp `| 0` itself is a bitwise operation that does nothing, but in javascript floats are [converted to ints before any bitwise operation](https://huytd.github.io/bitwise-float-int-trick.html). So it's something like how `+ ''` doesn't really do anything but can be used to convert things to strings.

Comment: It's not the same as `Math.floor` but it is the correct thing to do here. It's an operator so it's faster than `Math.floor` if only because at any time while running some code can do `Math.floor = someOtherFunction` and they can't do the same for '|'. On the other hand as for `Math.floor` and `|` being different try `Math.floor(-1.5)` vs `-1.5 | 0`.  By the way you don't need the parentheses. `|` has a very low precedence.

Answer (score 23):

Say you want to choose a random item that is different from the last time (not really random, but still a common requirement)...

```js
/**
 * Return a random element from an array that is
 * different than `last` (as long as the array has > 1 items). 
 * Return null if the array is empty.
*/
function getRandomDifferent(arr, last = undefined) {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return null;
  } else if (arr.length === 1) {
    return arr[0];
  } else {
    let num = 0;
    do {
      num = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    } while (arr[num] === last);
    return arr[num];
  }
}
```

Implement like this:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3];
const r1 = getRandomDifferent(arr);
const r2 = getRandomDifferent(arr, r1); // r2 is different than r1.
```

Answer (score 15):

Many of the offered solutions add a method to a specific Array which restricts it's use to just that array. This solution is reusable code that works for any array and can be made type safe.

##### TypeScript

```js
export function randChoice<T>(arr: Array<T>): T {
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]
}
```

##### JavaScript

```js
function randChoice(arr) {
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]
}
```

Answer (score 13):

If you have fixed values (like a month name list) and want a one-line solution

```
var result = ['January', 'February', 'March'][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]
```

The second part of the array is an access operation as described in [Why does [5,6,8,7][1,2] = 8 in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421013/why-does-5-6-8-71-2-8-in-javascript/7421030#7421030)

Comment: Such code is a bad and harmful practice. It should never be used in production. It has low readability and it has a hardcoded array length. The person changing the array input may forget to edit the length hardcoded in the end.

Comment: @Seagull OP never asked for an specific environment. Also this comment is meaningless as it could be applied to almost all the answers in this question ;)

Comment: But most people arrive to this question from Google search and the may use the solution in other scenarios than original OP.

Comment: @Seagull Haha people are free to decide which approach to use, I'm not the clean code guideliness faq!

Comment: I like the readability of this, just came to the same solution myself

Comment: I fully agree, having to hardcode the array length this way is simply very bad coding, asking for maintenance issues...

Answer (score 13):

If you want to write it on one line, like Pascual's solution, another solution would be to write it using ES6's find function (based on the fact, that the probability of randomly selecting one out of `n` items is `1/n`):

```js
var item = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'].find((_, i, ar) => Math.random() < 1 / (ar.length - i));
console.log(item);
```

Use that approach for testing purposes and if there is a good reason to not save the array in a seperate variable only. Otherwise the other answers (`floor(random()*length` and using a seperate function) are your way to go.

Answer (score 9):

[Faker.js](https://github.com/faker-js/faker) has many utility functions for generating random test data. It is a good option in the context of a test suite:

```
const faker = require('faker');
faker.helpers.arrayElement(['January', 'February', 'March']);
```

As commenters have mentioned, you generally should not use this library in production code.

Comment: For a simple problem like this, adding a dependency for an entire library is unnecessary and adds to code bloat. If anything, you could potentially recommend the actual method from `Faker` which selects a random array element.

Comment: "Simple problem" like this one are usually solved by libraries that provide a simple solution to a problem that hundred of persons already had to face with. Those libraries are usually robust and well debugged and deals with various caveats we don't want to re-implement. It would be typically the situation where I would recommend to use a library.

Comment: Than you should just copy that one method from the library and put it in a utils file

Comment: The advice that libraries should be assessed for cost/benefit WRT page weight when they are shipped to a web browser is sound advice and I whole-heartedly agree that shipping Faker.js to a browser would be ridiculous. However, the question does not mention which JS runtime is being used. For a NodeJS-based runtime heavier dependencies are perfectly reasonable which is the case for where I am using Faker.js - in Cucumber JS test suites.

Comment: I'm working on tests that already use faker.js so this is a helpful answer to me.

Comment: @Pixxl One that requires a random element from an array will typically also require many other ways of randomly generating mock data. so using a library like faker.js makes sense.

Answer (score 8):

Editing Array prototype can be harmful. Here it is a simple function to do the job.

```
function getArrayRandomElement (arr) {
  if (arr && arr.length) {
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
  }
  // The undefined will be returned if the empty array was passed
}
```

Usage:

```
// Example 1
var item = getArrayRandomElement(['January', 'February', 'March']);

// Example 2
var myArray = ['January', 'February', 'March'];
var item = getArrayRandomElement(myArray);
```

Answer (score 7):

If you need to fetch a random item more than once, then, obviously you would use a function. One way is to make that function a method of the `Array.prototype`, but that will normally get you shouted down for tampering with built in prototypes.

However, you can add the method to the specific array itself:

```js
var months = ['January', 'February', 'March'];
months.random = function() {
    return this[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.length)];
};
```

That way you can use `months.random()` as often as you like without interfering with the generic `Array.prototype`.

As with any random function, you run the risk of getting the same value successively. If you don’t want that, you will need to track the previous value with another property:

```js
months.random=function() {
    var random;
    while((random=this[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.length)]) == this.previous);
    this.previous=random;
    return random;
};
```

If you’re going to do this sort of thing often, and you don’t want to tamper with `Array.prototype`, you can do something like this:

```js
function randomValue() {
    return this[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.length)];
}

var data = [ … ];
var moreData = [ … ];

data.random=randomValue;
moreData.random=randomValue;
```

Answer (score 5):

To get [crypto-strong](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues) random item form array use

```js
let rndItem = a=> a[rnd()*a.length|0];
let rnd = ()=> crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0]/2**32;

var myArray = ['January', 'February', 'March'];

console.log( rndItem(myArray) )
```

Answer (score 4):

Recursive, standalone function which can return any number of items (identical to [lodash.sampleSize](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sampleSize)):

```
function getRandomElementsFromArray(array, numberOfRandomElementsToExtract = 1) {
    const elements = [];

    function getRandomElement(arr) {
        if (elements.length < numberOfRandomElementsToExtract) {
            const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)
            const element = arr.splice(index, 1)[0];

            elements.push(element)

            return getRandomElement(arr)
        } else {
            return elements
        }
    }

    return getRandomElement([...array])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to, but more general than, @Jacob Relkin's solution:

This is ES2015:

```
const randomChoice = arr => {
    const randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    return arr[randIndex];
};
```

The code works by selecting a random number between 0 and the length of the array, then returning the item at that index.

Answer (score 2):

`var item = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];`

or equivalent shorter version:

`var item = myArray[(Math.random()*myArray.length)|0];`

Sample code:

```js
var myArray = ['January', 'February', 'March'];    
var item = myArray[(Math.random()*myArray.length)|0];
console.log('item:', item);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple function:

```
var myArray = ['January', 'February', 'March'];
function random(array) {
     return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)]
}
random(myArray);
```

Or:

```
var myArray = ['January', 'February', 'March'];
function random() {
     return myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)]
}
random();
```

Comment: It would be better to set the myArrayy variable inside your function as to not pollute the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, better than messing around with prototypes , or declaring it just in time, I prefer exposing it to window:

```
window.choice = function() {
  if (!this.length || this.length == 0) return;
  if (this.length == 1) return this[0];
  return this[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.length)];
}
```

Now anywhere on your app you call it like:

```
var rand = window.choice.call(array)
```

This way you can still use `for(x in array)` loop properly

Comment: I wasn't here when anyone downvoted it, and I didn't downvote it, but my guess is that exposing it to window is basically declaring a global variable. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613310/ive-heard-global-variables-are-bad-what-alternative-solution-should-i-use

Comment: You shouldn't ever use `for...in` on arrays, or even in general.  You run the risk of walking the prototype chain.  It's also meant for all properties of an object, not all indices in an array.  If you want to use an iterator on an array, use `for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++){}`.  Even better, use something like `Array.prototype.forEach` instead.

Comment: I do not prefer this because it pollutes the global scope. You could say this might be the only one to be there, but it will give habits of violating that good practice.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way around the top answer's complications, just by concatenating the variable rand to another variable that allows that number to be displayed inside the calling of myArray[];. By deleting the new array created and toying around with it's complications, I've come up with a working solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

var myArray = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May'];    

var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);

var concat = myArray[rand];

function random() {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (concat);
}
</script>

<button onClick="random();">
Working Random Array generator
</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm confused why `concat` is ever changing here... `random` itself isn't changing it, and nothing else is getting called more than once....

Comment: This solution doesn't entirely make sense. Why are you creating a variable called concat?

Answer (score 0):

```js
static generateMonth() { 
const theDate = ['January', 'February', 'March']; 
const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
return theDate[randomNumber];
};
```

You set a constant variable to the array, you then have another constant that chooses randomly between the three objects in the array and then the function simply returns the results.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for a true one-liner I came to this:

```
['January', 'February', 'March'].reduce((a, c, i, o) => { return o[Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(o.length))]; })
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding a method on prototype of array you can get random values easly.

In this example you can get single or multiple random values from array.

You can run to test code by clicking snippet button.

```js
Array.prototype.random = function(n){
  if(n&&n>1){
    const a = [];
    for(let i = 0;i<n;i++){
      a.push(this[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.length)]);
    }
    return a;
  } else {
    return this[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.length)];
  }
}

const mySampleArray =  ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'];

mySampleArray.random(); // return any random value etc. 'a', 'b'
mySampleArray.random(3); //retun an array with random values etc: ['b','f','a'] , ['d','b','d']

alert(mySampleArray.random());
alert(mySampleArray.random(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

- Use Math.random() function to get the random number between(0-1, 1
  exclusive).
- Multiply it by the array length to get the numbers
  between(0-arrayLength).
- Use Math.floor() to get the index ranging
  from(0 to arrayLength-1).

> const arr = ["foo","bar"];
> const randomlyPickedString=arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
> console.log(randomlyPickedString);

Method 2:

- The random(a, b) method is used to generates a number between(a to b, b exclusive).
- Taking the floor value to range the numbers from (1 to arrayLength).
- Subtract 1 to get the index ranging from(0 to arrayLength-1).

> const arr = ["foo","bar"];
> const randomlyPickedString=arr[Math.floor(random(1, 5))-1];
> console.log(randomlyPickedString);

Answer (score -1):

A generic way to get random element(s):

```js
let some_array = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'];
let months = random_elems(some_array, 3);

console.log(months);

function random_elems(arr, count) {
  let len = arr.length;
  let lookup = {};
  let tmp = [];

  if (count > len)
    count = len;

  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    let index;
    do {
      index = ~~(Math.random() * len);
    } while (index in lookup);
    lookup[index] = null;
    tmp.push(arr[index]);
  }

  return tmp;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is an example of how to do it:

```
$scope.ctx.skills = data.result.skills;
    $scope.praiseTextArray = [
    "Hooray",
    "You\'re ready to move to a new skill", 
    "Yahoo! You completed a problem", 
    "You\'re doing great",  
    "You succeeded", 
    "That was a brave effort trying new problems", 
    "Your brain was working hard",
    "All your hard work is paying off",
    "Very nice job!, Let\'s see what you can do next",
    "Well done",
    "That was excellent work",
    "Awesome job",
    "You must feel good about doing such a great job",
    "Right on",
    "Great thinking",
    "Wonderful work",
    "You were right on top of that one",
    "Beautiful job",
    "Way to go",
    "Sensational effort"
  ];

  $scope.praiseTextWord = $scope.praiseTextArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*$scope.praiseTextArray.length)];
```

Answer (score -3):

Create one random value and pass to array

Please try following code..

```
//For Search textbox random value
var myPlaceHolderArray = ['Hotels in New York...', 'Hotels in San Francisco...', 'Hotels Near Disney World...', 'Hotels in Atlanta...'];
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myPlaceHolderArray.length);
var Placeholdervalue = myPlaceHolderArray[rand];

alert(Placeholdervalue);
```

Comment: This answer uses the same solution as the already accepted answer. You should refrain from adding the same solution twice and instead only bring up possible other alternatives that would contribute more to the conversation.

Answer (score -3):

[randojs](https://randojs.com) makes this a little more simple and readable:

```js
console.log( rando(['January', 'February', 'March']).value );
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: some people aren't a fan of sourcing in libraries for code they could write themselves, even if it would make things faster and more readable. if the library goes down for some reason, your website now has a glitch. randojs doesn't go down, but they don't know that because it's not as well known as libraries like jQuery for example

Answer (score -8):

I am really surprised nobody tried to use native random values:

```
array[Date.now()%array.length]
```

It will not work for array length over 160000000000, but I am sure you will never create arrays like this

**UPD**

As far as you question is how to pick random value from array called `myArray` (with len=3), the solution should be:

```
myArray[Date.now()%myArray.length]
```

Comment: I didn’t downvote you, but I can’t see how your solution is in any related to the question. I assume other’s can’t either.

Comment: So .. yes it "kind of" works, but then again not really. It's being downvoted because `Date.now()` has nothing to do with randomness and is quite deterministic indeed.
I get that it might feel "random" enough in some use-cases though

Comment: @nuts `Date.now()` everytime returns different values, this way it cannot be detemined for 100% accurace, moreover in case for array about 3 elements.

Comment: @EgorRandomize these Date-values are highly deterministic. That is the oppositve of random. Again: Yes, as a user you get perceived randomness, but it has nothing to do with actual randomness. (Btw: I didn't even downvote ^^)

Comment: @nuts yes, I agree with your thoughts, but how can I tag my question as another view-point? Because here I can see only `Math.Rand` implemented solutions, as far as it is one pseudo-random function

Comment: Downvoted, because it's *not random*, and not an appropriate answer.

Comment: @Brad how can you prove it? This is literally the most appropriate answer & the shortest answer.

Comment: @Egor Do we really need proof beyond the obvious that time is deterministic?  Fine... call it in a loop and watch all the repeated values you get.  It's a bad side effect that will bite you at some point... if not today, it will in the future.  It's like, what, 15 extra characters of typing to do it the right way?

Comment: @Brad who was talking about loops? Where 15 extra chars came from? There are no such factors in original question. We have 3 different cases and one attempt to take one of them. Millisecond logic is perfect for this particular situation.

Comment: @Egor The question is generic and highly referenced.  It simply asks how to get a random value from an array.  Your answer does not return a **random value** from an array.  You asked for proof that your answer is not random.  I gave it to you, with a very clear and common example.  If your answer had some tradeoff of determinism-for-other-goodness, and if you called out that tradeoff in your answer, it'd be appropriate.  Instead, you've tacked on a bad answer to a decade-old question, that has no advantage over one of the several good answers already posted.  Hence, my downvote.